# Silicone socks for nozzle only?

Tags: hotend, nozzle

Is there a readily available silicone sock that goes *just* over the nozzle, to supplement an existing sock around the heat block body? I've seen a product for the E3D V6 that goes around the entire assembly and only exposes the tip of the nozzle:

[image: E3D V6 "SOCK PRO"]

but it's for a specific block shape and doesn't facilitate easy nozzle change. What I'd like is a piece that fits over just the nozzle, with a friction fit to the existing block sock. The benefits I'm looking to get from this are:

- reduced radiative heat transfer from the nozzle to the already-printed material
- more consistent/stable temperature in the nozzle under air flow from cooling fans
- eliminating sticking of PETG to the nozzle body

Comment: When you change the nozzle, do you end up having to take the sock off the heat block to get a wrench on there anyway? Is there something with your setup where you can’t slip the sock off?

Comment: You only need a wrench on the heat block if the hotend is not structurally sound (using the heatbreak structurally). Otherwise you just use a socket or open end wrench on the nozzle.

Comment: What nozzle system do you use? The official procedure with the E3D nozzles like you pictured the socks for, is to hold the heat block with a wrench or pliers, so you aren’t torquing the heat break or the aluminum cold end’s delicate threads: https://e3d-online.dozuki.com/Guide/Changing+Nozzles/45

Comment: If you have a concept that could improve on existing designs, you could potentially cast your own, by 3D printing a mold and using a high temp RTV silicone like this stuff for engine gaskets: https://www.permatex.com/products/gasketing/gasket-makers/permatex-high-temp-red-rtv-silicone-gasket/?locale=en_us

Comment: @ChinchillaWafers: I'm not using E3D. I just showed those as an example of a similar product. I'm using MK8 style hotend, but whatever I use in the future will also have proper structural bolting of the heat block to the heat sink and toolhead body, not relying on the heatbreak as a structural component like E3D and many others do.